# Container that has a DataSource to put a bunch of controls in?

Tags: asp.net, datasource, containers

I need a container that I can set a custom `DataSource` on so that I can bind a bunch of controls inside of it to a data object. I can't set a `DataSource` on my `Page` or my `asp:Panel`, so what container can I use that has a `DataSource`? I have a *lot* of controls and properties, and I don't want to bind them all manually, I'd prefer to use a control or something that has a `DataSource` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gridview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx), [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx), [FormView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.aspx)  Need something different?

Comment: I basically need an invisible container for all my Controls so I can bind to them... GridView and ListView are out, but FormView sounds promising... is it pretty much a transparent control?

Comment: you can set it to `visible="false"` or set to a style with `display:none` css if thats what you mean.  If you mean does it have a border it does not unless you style it to.